# iOS 13 MapKit: MKMapItem.pointOfInterestCategory is nil?

Tags: mapkit, mklocalsearch, ios13

I am trying to get  MKMapItem.pointOfInterestCategory on iOS 13 beta using this unit test:

```
func testPointOfInterests() {

    let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    let mkSearchExpectation = expectation(description: "MKLocalSearch")

    // Sagrada Família, Barcelone
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.40359499, longitude: 2.17436157)
    request.region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Sagrada Família"
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        request.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter(excluding: [.atm])
    }
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start { (response, error) in
        mkSearchExpectation.fulfill()
        XCTAssertNil(error)
        XCTAssertNotNil(response)
        guard let response = response else {
            return
        }

        for mapItem in response.mapItems {
            dump(mapItem)
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                if let category = mapItem.pointOfInterestCategory {
                    print(category)
                }
            }
        }


    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 10.0) {
        error in
        if let error = error {
            XCTFail(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```

I get a relevant mapItem, but MKMapItem.pointOfInterestCategory is nil.

A similar test using Apples Maps app shows that Apples servers know that the Sagrada Família in Barcelona is a church.

What am I doing wrong? I'd like to get the pointOfInterestCategory running on iOS 13 beta.